# Declaring doubles in Java - locally once or repetitively from an ArrayList<Double>?

Tags: java, eclipse, runtime, memory-efficient, coding-efficiency

I have a question about style and efficiency in Java or in programming in general. The following code is reading some
file which contains a lot of constants for a rather big calculation (not shown here):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        ArrayList<Double> constants = new ArrayList<Double>();

        try {
            FileReader fr = new FileReader(*PATH*);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);

            for (String line = br.readLine(); line != null; line = br.readLine()) {
                constants.add(Double.valueOf(line.split("\t")[1]));
            }
        br.close();

        double qh = constants.get(0);      // [1]
        double lambda = constants.get(1);
        ......
        ......
        System.out.println(qh);
     ......
 }
```

Now: Is it better (meaning good programming style/runtime efficiency) to declare each variable seperately at the beginning (like at [1]) or to invoke it from the ArrayList each and every time it pops up within the calculation?

Comment: Pick whatever is more readable; reading code is more important than writing it.

Comment: @JacobG. not true when it comes to computationally intensive calculations.  The better algorithm may be the less readable one.

Comment: @mcfinnigan: Yes, there are exceptions.

Comment: I'd say the most readable would be to have a `.properties` file of some sort and access the values by key. What would happen in your example, if you suddenly changed the order of constants in your file? Then `constants.get(1)` wouldn't map to `lambda` anymore and everything breaks.

Comment: @mcfinnigan Of course there are exceptions, however that was directed at this case where both options wouldn't make a difference.

Comment: @QBrute But isn't this the same as putting them into a hashmap and invoke them over and over again when needed? (which means inefficient)

Comment: @JacobG. OP explicitly mentions these will be used in a large calculation.

Comment: @mcfinnigan So? `ArrayList#get` is `O(1)`; it's negligible.

Comment: @JacobG. will the JVM apply the same sort of optimisations to list.get() as it would to a simple constant reference?  I'm not sure it would, and this sort of compiler level optimisation can make a large difference in long-running calculations.

Answer (score 3):

Retrieving them repeatedly as needed from the ArrayList will likely be less readable than reusing a nicely-named identifier. Also likely slightly less efficient, though that's probably not going to matter.

I'd probably move this reading of constants¹ from a file into its own class and expose the loaded constants as read-only members of that class. That way, `main` isn't cluttered with the file-read logic, and when you use the constants, not only do they have nice clear names, but it's also clear (depending on naming of the class and the instance) where they came from.

---

¹ (If they're *constants*, why do they have to come from a file at runtime?)

Comment: A file makes sense if you're implementing some sort of algorithm that needs to be tweaked for testing purposes.

Comment: @[1]: very very good question! I adopted this approach from a colleague and didnt question  it

Answer (score 2):

There may be little difference between storing the constants in an Arraylist in a general program, but if as you hint you're doing heavy computation work with these constants, you may be able to gain benefit from compiler optimisations if you delare the various constants as doubles within your source code.

Personally, my opinion is that the arraylist method is overly complex and requires you to store the index positions of the various constants anyway - you may as well just define the constants themselves.

Also, an example:

```
double currentVal = RAYLEY_NUMBER * DIFFUSION_COEFFICIENT;\\
```

is much more descriptive than

```
double currentVal = list.get(37) * list.get(44);
```

#### Followup to this post - I tested it.

So I was curious enough about the Arraylist doubles vs constant doubles that I wrote a (admittedly basic) benchmark to test it with jmh.  The classes are as equivalent as I can make them - the algorithm is successive multiplication and division of the initial value by each constant.

```
class ArraylistTest {
    public static List<Double> constants = new ArrayList<Double>();
    static {
        for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
            constants.add((double)i);
        }
    }
    private int iterations = 1000;
    private double[] results = new double[iterations];

    public void performComplexCalculation() {
        for(int i = 0; i < iterations; i++) {
            double curval = 1.0;

            curval *= constants.get(0);
            curval /= constants.get(1);
            ... 
            curval /= constants.get(19);

            results[i] = curval;
        }
    }
}

class ConstantsTest {
    private int iterations = 1000;
    private double[] results = new double[iterations];

    static Double c1 = 1.0;
    static Double c2 = 2.0;
    ... 
    static Double c20 = 20.0;

    public ConstantsTest() {

    }

    public void performComplexCalculation() {
        for(int i = 0; i < iterations; i++) {
            double curval = 1.0;

            curval *= c1;
            curval /= c2;
            ... 
            curval /= c20;

            results[i] = curval;
        }
    }
}
```

These are the results I saw from jmh:

#### ArrayList-based

```
Result: 1841787.017 ±(99.9%) 41096.602 ops/s [Average]
  Statistics: (min, avg, max) = (729913.738, 1841787.017, 2036582.810), stdev = 174005.587
  Confidence interval (99.9%): [1800690.415, 1882883.619]
```

#### Constants-based

```
Result: 1841787.017 ±(99.9%) 41096.602 ops/s [Average]
  Statistics: (min, avg, max) = (729913.738, 1841787.017, 2036582.810), stdev = 174005.587
  Confidence interval (99.9%): [1800690.415, 1882883.619]
```

#### Overall side-by-side

```
Benchmark                             Mode  Samples        Score  Score error  Units
b.MyBenchmark.testArraylistMethod    thrpt      200  1841787.017    41096.602  ops/s
b.MyBenchmark.testConstantsMethod    thrpt      200  1950015.802    35899.352  ops/s
```

So roughly 6% faster in my contrived example. Most likely negligible in real-world cases.

Comment: And more descriptive than `double currentVal = list.get(RAYLEY_NUMBER_INDEX) * list.get(DIFFUSION_COEFFICIENT_INDEX);`

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that is it probably more efficient to make local variables, unless there are many variables that you never end up using.

The slightly longer answer is that you shouldn't worry about performance unless and until you have identified that this is a performance bottleneck that actually matters.  Worry about code readability when you are writing the code, and, for the 1% of you code where performance actually matters, find that 1% by profiling and then tune just that.

But the real answer is that you should use a properties file and read the values into an instance of a Constants class that you create.